# JQuery how to get inline style value

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do hover image but how do I get the original inline css background value returned?

```
<div style="background-image: url(orig.jpg)" data-alt-bg="orig_hover.jpg">

$("div[data-alt-bg]").hover(function() {
    var backgroundnew = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-alt-bg') + "')";
    $(this).css('background-image', backgroundnew)
}, function() {
    var backgroundOrig = XXX??????????XXXXXX??????????
    $(this).css('background-image', backgroundOrig)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the original background  as custom data attribute and update based on the data attribute value in second callback function.

```js
$("div[data-alt-bg]").hover(function() {
  $(this).data('bg', $(this).css('background-image'));
  var backgroundnew = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-alt-bg') + "')";
  $(this).css('background-image', backgroundnew)
}, function() {
  $(this).css('background-image', $(this).data('bg'))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image: url(orig.jpg)" data-alt-bg="orig_hover.jpg">hi</div>
```

---

**FYI :** Always it's better to use css since there is option with [`:hover` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that using simple CSS rule.

```css
div {
  background-image: url('orig.jpg')
 }
div:hover {
  background-image: url('https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpf1/v/t1.0-1/p200x200/11182094_10153030955874652_1696866992468729401_n.jpg?oh=ba799406635ee2de0f20e497826076e6&oe=57D55DF6&__gda__=1472963214_d7a1f64437e4e3b7fa6cef8520d091d3')
 }
```

```html
<div>Something</div>
```

However if you still want to use jQuery. Persist the `original` image in cache using `.data()`

```js
$("div[data-alt-bg]").hover(function() {
  var backgroundnew = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-alt-bg') + "')";
  //Persisit original in cache
  var orig = $(this).css('background-image');

  $(this).data('orig', orig).css('background-image', backgroundnew)
}, function() {
  //Read data from cache
  var backgroundOrig = $(this).data('orig');

  $(this).css('background-image', backgroundOrig)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image: url(orig.jpg)" data-alt-bg="orig_hover.jpg">something</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$(this).data("alt-bg");`

```
$("div[data-alt-bg]").hover(function() {
    var backgroundnew = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-alt-bg') + "')";
    $(this).css('background-image', backgroundnew)
}, function() {
    var backgroundOrig = $(this).data("alt-bg"); // use data
    $(this).css('background-image', backgroundOrig)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following approach:

We can put the original background image into `$.data` before changing it on `hover` and on `hoverout` we can read it again:

```js
$("div[data-alt-bg]").hover(function() {
  var backgroundnew = "url('" + $(this).attr('data-alt-bg') + "')";
  var oldBackground = $(this).css('background-image');
  $(this).data("originalBackground",oldBackground);
  $(this).css('background-image', backgroundnew)
}, function() {
  var backgroundOrig = $(this).data("originalBackground");
  
  console.log(backgroundOrig);
  
  $(this).css('background-image', backgroundOrig)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image: url(orig.jpg)" data-alt-bg="orig_hover.jpg">Hello</div>
```